# CSS background: set position then do a shift?

Tags: background-image, css, background-position

The background-position property can be set in a variety of ways such as "top right" or "16px 16px" or "50% 75%" etc.

**Question**: is there a way to position a background image then offset that position?

For example: set the background-position to "top right" then shift it left 16px and down 16px using "-16px 16px"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with (crossbrowser) CSS. You will have to use javascript for this one.

For IE you could have a look at CSS expressions, but as mentioned, not really crossbrowser, as in IE only :)

Answer (score 1):

you can set a static value for background-position
e.g. background-position:800px 10px 0px 0px;

Comment: This option works, but I'm looking for a method that doesen't require knowing the width/height of the element.